# Windows Forms in C# cancel event

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am creating my first C# application using Windows Forms, and I am running into a little trouble.  I am trying to validate the contents placed inside a particular cell of a DataGridView control.  If the contents are not valid, I want to warn the user and highlight the cell's background in red.  Additionally, I want to cancel the event prevent the user from moving to another cell.  When I try to do this, the message box successfully displays, but the background color never changes.  Does anyone know why?  Here is my code:

```
        private void dataInventory_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                if (!Utilities.validName(e.FormattedValue))
                {
                    dataInventory.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    MessageBox.Show("The value entered is not valid.");
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataInventory.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                break;
```

//More stuff

Answer (score 1):

MessageBoxes are not the best tool to use during validation.  By making `e.Cancel = true;`, you are telling the grid to not let the cell lose focus, but the MessageBox makes the cursor leave the control.  Things go a little haywire.

The coloring part should be working, but because the cell is highlighted, you probably aren't seeing the result.

Try changing the code to use the grid's ability to display error icons:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Fix this";
e.Cancel = true;
```

Use the CellEndEdit event to clear the message.

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = String.Empty;
}
```

See [Walkthrough: Validating Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx)

Comment: That's definitely a nice touch, but is there a way for me to change the error text of the cell itself so that each of my rows can have separate error texts?  When I try to do this, using dataInventory.Rows[(int)row].Cells[(int)column].ErrorText = "The product entered is not valid.";  The system fails to show the error flag.  I assume this is for the same reason the cell was failing to highlight: the user was selecting the cell.  Is there a good way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: @user1556487 Difficult to answer that.  If you have row headers visible and you set the error to the row the way I did, then you get a red circle with tooltip information with your error text.  Comes down to style really.  You could always just show a red label somewhere next to the grid with your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dataInventory.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
```